# Generate float matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to generate a 5x4 matrix with random float numbers between -1 and 1:
I'm currently using the following:

```
WeightHiden = randi ( [-1 1], 5 , 4 );
```

but it only gives me integer numbers.

Comment: yes i meant an integer number not real number sry

Comment: @user3074215 So edit your question appropriately. Respect the community.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rand` instead.

> Example 1
>   Generate values from the uniform distribution on the interval [a, b]:
>
> r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);

```
r= -1 + 2 .* rand( 5 , 4 )
```